# Since when is it obligated to include an empty constructor in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I was practicing dome Java OO principles, when I encountered with this. I create to POJOs and when trying to make objects from it, if an empty constructor isn't defined, it wont compile.

I find this weird because I used to do that and the JVM included a default one for me. Is it new in Java 7? Am I missing something?

Here is the sample code I made

```
public class Dog {
String name;
String race;
int age;
/*
public Dog() {
    If this isn't included, it doesn't compile if I try to
    create no-args objects. 
}*/

public Dog (String _name) {
    this.name = _name;
}

public Dog (String _name, String _race) {
    this.name = _name;
    this.race = _race;
}

public Dog (String _name, String _race, int _age) {
    this.name = _name;
    this.race = _race;
    this.age = _age;
}
```

}

Comment: This code compiles just fine without the no-arg constructor. Can you share the code that's failing and the error you're getting?

Comment: @Mureinik it will fail if you try to create a default `Dog` (no args)

Comment: IMO as soon as you start to use the word "weird", your first stop should be a book and not a forum. Something is only weird when you have a mess in your head which you need to un-weird.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `Dog newDog = new Dog();` will not work in your current code, because you have not defined it.

A default constructor will **only** be automatically generated if no other constructors are present.

> **You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors.** This default constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the superclass. In this situation, the compiler will complain if the superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor so you must verify that it does. If your class has no explicit superclass, then it has an implicit superclass of Object, which does have a no-argument constructor.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 2):

If you define constructors with arguments, you also have to define a default one with no arguments.
In this case, trying to create a new Dog (`Dog d = new Dog()`) can't be done because the constructor with no args is not defined.

"If a class defines an explicit constructor, it no longer has a default constructor to set the state of the objects.
 If such a class requires a default constructor, its implementation must be provided. Any attempt to call the default constructor will be a compile time error if an explicit default constructor is not provided in such a case."

http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-constructors